# "Disciple" hat is missing in the earned hat list

Tags: bug, profile-page, winter-bash-2020

I've earned the "Disciple" hat today (`17/12/2020`), but, when I check the hats I got so far, the "Disciple" is not shown in the earned hat list - even if the user has the "Disciple" on.

[My profile in Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4092887/mauricio-arias-olave?tab=topactivity#winter-bash) - where I earned the "Disciple" hat.

[Another user's profile](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/164138/thelper?tab=topactivity#winter-bash) - just found at random that has the same "Disciple" but, it's not shown in their earned hat list.

Is this a bug?

Comment: My balalaika hat is also gone.

Comment: @GEdgar yes - same bug. But it's likely if you wait a day or two, it may come back.

Comment: @Catija I'll keep "Disciple" until this bug is fixed. Thanks for the comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it's a bug and erroneously awarded hats have been revoked. [An employee stated the following](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/56467555):

> **mea culpa #3** - really hope this is the last time, but I just cleared all hat owners for balalaika and disciple. Both are secret, and both had something messed up with their triggers (and if I didn't clear them, then would be very hard to figure out what they are for). If you earned [them], they will be awarded to you again shortly.